# Mac OS X 10.7.4 install helper tool in Qt Application

Tags: c++, macos, qt, sign

i am using SMJobBless function for install my helper tool to launch daemons, as it described in this article - http://atnan.com/blog/2012/02/29/modern-privileged-helper-tools-using-smjobbless-plus-xpc/ , and here also - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SMJobBless/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html.
Few month ago everything with this was well. And new helper tool was installed with success.
But last few days (maybe after updating to 10.7.4, but it not work on others versions too) i have strange problem with installation of helper tool. After user typed password to mac auth window helper tool does not intalled. And i can see this syslog text:

Jul 27 18:30:28 Illia-Greens-MacBook-Pro authorizationhost[4318] : SFBuiltinEntitled: MyApp.app is not entitled for com.apple.ServiceManagement.daemons.modify
Jul 27 18:30:28 Illia-Greens-MacBook-Pro launchdadd[4313] : FAILURE: Job com.bsd.OpenVPNHelper is not loaded in launchd.

What is wrong? And few days before it work.

Comment: Yes, i am used codesign utility for it with authorized key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps my answer is late for you, but i hope it can helps another Qt Developers. I have create a project in Qt to show how to sign, install an execute a privileged helper tool, you can see the code here: https://github.com/mbsanchez/QtPrivilegedHelperExample

I have created it, because there is not documentation on how to install a privileged helper tool using a Qt Application.